# How do I get a UISwitch or UITextField to respond to a UITapGestureRecognizer without switching/going into edit mode respectively?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uigesturerecognizer, uiswitch, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a custom UIViewController that all my ViewControllers inherit from.  On this Controller I have a UITapGestureRecognizer.  I also have a boolean property called inHelpMode.

The idea is that when the view is in help mode, tapping a control brings up a popup with information regarding the control's function.

This works fine for most controls, with two notable exceptions: UISwitch and UITextField.

The first switches and the second goes into edit mode.

I have tried setting enabled to NO on those controls when I enter help mode, which prevents the controls from responding, but also prevents the popup from displaying.  The same happens when setting the Controller as the UItextField's delegate and overriding textFieldShouldBeginEditing.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting userInteractionEnabled to NO for the UISwitch and UITextField when entering edit mode. Don't forget to set it back to YES when leaving help mode. If this works, then it must be because those two controls still do some touch handling even when enabled is set to NO. By setting userInteractionEnabled to NO, you are disabling them at the UIView level, so hopefully that will cause the tap gesture to be ignored by them.

Comment: When I set the userInteractionEnabled to NO the controls no longer react to the tap gesture to display the popover.

Comment: Do you have just one tap gesture added to the view that contains all of these controls? Or tap gesture on each of the controls? And if it's just one tap gesture, do you then do some calculations to detect if the tap location is within the bounds of any of the controls?

Comment: It's just one tap gesture on the base view class that all my views inherit from.  I call hitTest on the tap method and then compare the tag of the controll to a list that contains the popover messages.